# how I display value of Participants who are in both events

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

Q. Create a class named Participant with fields for a name, age, and street address. Include a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field and a toString() method that returns a String containing all the values.

Also include an equals() method that determines two Participants are equal if they have the same values in all three fields.

Create an application with two arrays of at least 5 Participants each--one holds the Participants in the mini-marathon and the other holds Participants in the diving competition. Prompt the user for Participants who are in both events save the files as Participant.java and TwoEventParticipants.java.*/

Here is my code so far.  **How do I display the value of Participants who are in both events ?**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.*;

    public class TwoEventParticipants {
         private  static Participant mini[] = new Participant[2];
         private  static Participant diving[] = new Participant[2];

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String name="";;
              String add="";
              int age=0;
            Participant p=new Participant(name, age, add);
            Participant p1=new Participant(name, age, add);
            setParticipant();
        setParticipant1();

            displayDetail();
            displayDetail1();
            //Arrays.sort(p1);
            if (p.equals(p1)){

                 System.out.println(p);
            }else{
                System.out.println(p1);

            }

        }
        public static void setParticipant(){
            for (int x = 0; x < mini.length; x++) {

             System.out.println("Enter loan details for customer " + (x + 1) + "...");

    //Character loanType=getLoanType();
            //String loanType=getLoanType();
            String name=getName();
              String add=getAdd();
              int age=getAge();
             System.out.println();
             mini[x] = new Participant(name, age, add); //<--- Create the object with the data you collected and put it into your array.

            }
            }


        public static void setParticipant1(){

                for (int y = 0; y < diving.length; y++) {

             System.out.println("Enter loan details for customer " + (y + 1) + "...");

            String name=getName();
              String add=getAdd();
              int age=getAge();
             System.out.println();

             diving[y] = new Participant(name, age, add);
            }
        }
            // Participant p=new Participant(name,age,add);
        //displayDetails();
            // System.out.println(    p.toString());
        public static void displayDetail() {

             // for (int y = 0; y < diving.length; y++) {
            System.out.println("Name       \tAge   \tAddress");
          //Participant p=new Participant(name,age,add);
            for (int x = 0; x < mini.length; x++) {

                System.out.println(mini[x].toString());



                //    System.out.println(diving[y].toString());
            }
        }



        public static void displayDetail1() {


             System.out.println("Name       \tAge   \tAddress");
             for (int y = 0; y < diving.length; y++) {
                 System.out.println(diving[y].toString());
             }
        }

               public static String getName() {
                  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                  String name;
                 System.out.print(" Participant  name: ");
                  return name = sc.next();
               }

             // System.out.print(" Participant  name: ");
             // name = sc.next();
              public static int getAge() {
    int age;
                   System.out.print(" Enter age ");
                     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);;
                    return age= sc.nextInt();
              }
             public static String getAdd() {
                 String add;

                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);;
           System.out.print("Enter  Address: ");
           return add=sc.next(); 
             }


    }

            Participant with fields for a name, age, and street address   
    //
    public class Participant {


        private String name;
        private int age;
        private String address;


        public Participant(String name, int age, String address) {

            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + "      " + age + "       " + address    ;
        }

        // include an equals() method that determines two Participants are equal
        public boolean equals(Participant[] name,Participant[] age,Participant[] add) {
            if (this.name.equals(name)  && this.address.equals(address)&& age == age){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: how I display value of  Participants who are in both events

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to break up the initial blurb.  I also included your comment into the post.  You should do that yourself in the future, so that the question improves in quality.

Answer (score -1):

**This will work for you:**

```
for(Participant p : mini){
   if(diving.contain(p)){ 
       System.out.pringtln(p.toString()) ; 
   }
}
```